# bash script spwans itself and exit

Tags: bash, shell

So, previously I had a script that reads from text file(10 billion * 40 records with a pretty wide table). But I noticed there is a memory leak in Read Builtin in my CentOS 5.4
Right now I cannot upgrade my OS so I figure if I can read some records, run the same script within my current script and then kill the current script.
I have a file "test.txt", which contains 1-100000, one line for each number. And I want to read from this file 10000 a time until I transfer everything in this file to another file "callSelf.txt". The strange thing is I can get everything all the way to 90000 records but after that the script just stops and will not finish off those remaining 10000 lines. 
Note: I am using a named pipe for this process.

Does anyone has any idea what is going on here?
Thanks in advance.

```
PIPE="./pipe"
callSelf="./callSelf.txt"
counter=1
limit=9999

echo $$

while read LINE
do
   if [ $counter -gt $limit ]; then
     echo "$LINE" >> $callSelf
     ./callSelf.sh &
     exit 0
   fi
   ((counter++))
   echo "$LINE" >> $callSelf
done <$PIPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but this is a reprise of your script

```
while read
do
  echo $REPLY >> ./call_self.txt
  if (( ++counter > 9999 ))
  then
    ./call_self.sh &
    exit
  fi
done < ./pipe
```